# Many to Many Relationships without Double Junction Tables, Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have the following setup (which works fine). Using CodeFirst (CTP4).

A template has a list of influences, each influence gives a value to a trait.

```
public class Template
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Influence> Influences { get; set; }
}

public class Influence
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Trait Trait { get; set; }
    public virtual int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Trait
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Template is configured like this.

```
public class TemplateConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<Template>
{
    public TemplateConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(o => o.Id);
        Property(o => o.Id).IsIdentity();

        HasMany(o => o.Influences).WithRequired()
            .Map("templates.influences",
            (template, influence) => new {
                Template = template.Id,
                Influence = influence.Id
            });
        MapSingleType(o => new {
            o.Id
        });
    }
}
```

This **works** but I'd rather avoid the extra 'influences' table. Essentially, 'Influences' is simply an object and there doesn't need to be a central store for them. In fact, it is more beneficial to the design I am trying to approach if there is not a central table for them.

I wish to setup a scenario like this for the Template table... Basically **Influences** don't have their own table, they're just mapped by Trait/Value where they are used.

```
    public TemplateConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(u => u.Influences).WithMany()
            .Map("templates.influences",
            (template, influence) => new {
                Template = template.Id,
                Trait = influence.Trait.Id,
                Value = influence.Value
            });

        MapSingleType(c => new {
            c.Id
        }).ToTable("templates");
    }
```

When I try to do it this way, I get the exception on the Template Mapping.

> > **System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled**
> >
> > **The given expression includes an unrecognized pattern 'influence.Trait.Id'.**

---

Below is the entire project code, if needed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.EntityClient;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

namespace EFTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                    Database.SetInitializer<SampleDataContext>(new AlwaysRecreateDatabase<SampleDataContext>());
            var builder = new ModelBuilder();

            builder.Configurations.Add(new TraitConfiguration());
            builder.Configurations.Add(new InfluenceConfiguration());
            builder.Configurations.Add(new TemplateConfiguration());

            var model = builder.CreateModel();

            using (var context = new SampleDataContext(model))
            {
                var traits = new List<Trait>
                {
                    new Trait { Name = "Years" },
                    new Trait { Name = "Days" }
                };
                traits.ForEach(x => { context.Traits.Add(x); });
                context.SaveChanges();

                var templates = new List<Template>
                {
                    new Template
                    {
                        Influences = new List<Influence>
                        {
                            new Influence
                            {
                                Trait = context.Traits.Single( i => i.Name == "Years" ),
                                Value = 5
                            },
                            new Influence
                            {
                                Trait = context.Traits.Single( i => i.Name == "Days" ),
                                Value = 15
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                templates.ForEach(x => { context.Templates.Add(x); });
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

    public class SampleDataContext : DbContext
    {
        public SampleDataContext(DbModel model)
            : base(model)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Trait> Traits { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Influence> Influences { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Template> Templates { get; set; }
    }

    public class Trait
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class TraitConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<Trait>
    {
        public TraitConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(o => o.Id);
            Property(o => o.Id).IsIdentity();

            MapSingleType(o => new {
                o.Id,
                o.Name
            });
        }
    }

    public class Influence
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Trait Trait { get; set; }
        public virtual int Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class InfluenceConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<Influence>
    {
        public InfluenceConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(o => o.Id);
            Property(o => o.Id).IsIdentity();

            HasRequired(o => o.Trait);
            Property(o => o.Value);

            MapSingleType(o => new {
                o.Id,
                Trait = o.Trait.Id,
                o.Value
            });
        }
    }

    public class Template
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Influence> Influences { get; set; }
    }

    public class TemplateConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<Template>
    {
        public TemplateConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey(o => o.Id);
            Property(o => o.Id).IsIdentity();

            HasMany( o => o.Influences).WithRequired()
                .Map("templates.influences", 
                (template, influence) => new {
                    Template = template.Id,
                    Influence = influence.Id
                });
            MapSingleType(o => new {
                o.Id
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Anyone? Please? This is really driving me nuts.

Comment: You would get more responses if you posted an extremely short and simple code snippet that captures the problem in its minimal form instead of the huge amount of code you currently have. Also, when you say "it gives me errors", you _must_ include the full error/exception text, otherwise it's the equivalent of saying "it doesn't work".

Comment: Usually, when I post only what is necessary, I get people complaining that I am not providing enough code to be of any use. So this time I just posted the full project. I've edited it to be more concise, and left the full code at the bottom for any reference needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, new day new idea.

I have now installed CTP4 and got the same 4 tables as you got.

The reason why the many to many relation is produced, is that the model does not know that an influence will only be used by one template. Then you have to tell it that:

```
public class Influence
 {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Trait Trait { get; set; }
    public virtual int Value { get; set; }
    public virtual Template Template { get; set; }
 }
```

and:

```
    public InfluenceConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(o => o.Id);
        Property(o => o.Id).IsIdentity();
        Property(o => o.Value);

        MapSingleType(o => new
        {
            o.Id,
            Trait = o.Trait.Id,
            o.Value,
            Template = o.Template.Id
        });
    }
```

The influences table will then look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Influences](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Template] [int] NULL,
    [Trait] [int] NULL,
    [Value] [int] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Influences]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Influence_Template] FOREIGN KEY([Template])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Templates] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Influences] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Influence_Template]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Influences]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [Influence_Trait] FOREIGN KEY([Trait])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Traits] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Influences] CHECK CONSTRAINT [Influence_Trait]
GO
```

Comment: So what can I do about that? The Influence object needs to exist in C# as an object, but not in the database as an entity.

Comment: @Shiraz - I think you ahve that backwards.  He wants Template->Trait in the database, and Template->Influence->Trait in entitites

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking he is misunderstanding my question.

Comment: But I am not trying to store the Influence in the same table as the Trait, I am trying to store it in a Junction table that has a reference to the Template it is connected to.

Comment: I know I need THREE tables. I am trying to avoid having the fourth one. I want "TEMPLATES" "TRAITS" and then "TEMPLATE.TRAITS". Template.Traits will have a Template Id, a Trait Id, and a Value. That's my goal.

Comment: I don't understand. Within the Template configuration, I have an instance of an "Influence". I don't understand why it cannot get the Traid.Id and the Value out of that instance. The entire scenario just isn't making sense to me. I do not know if this is my code, or just a limitation of the Entity Framework as a whole.

Comment: I'm not using ObjectContext, I'm using DbContext. I need to be able to produce these results with the EntityConfigurations.

Comment: Also, ContextBuilder doesn't exist in CTP4. I can't even find it. The sample you provided can't even compile.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve the problem, still. The goal is to keep Influences from being aware of what they are attached to. dozens of objects will have lists of influences. I cannot have a reference to the Template on that entity. I guess this is just not possible to do with Entity Framework.

Comment: You may be able to use it. Try having one influence object, then for each object you need to connect it to create an object that inherits from influence. It is the inherited objects that you create a tables for. You will then get an influence table for each object that you are connected to. This is both a plus and a minus, on the plus side you will get less locking and contention. In your program you can still treat your influences as a single type by talking to them through a common interface or casting to the base class.

Comment: That might work. I'll try some things and get back to you. EntityFramework doesn't like letting me use 'Base Classes' for anything, as of CTP4...

Comment: Okay. The official answer is that this cannot be done in the Entity Framework as of yet. I have taken this up with Microsoft directly and received the same answer. Thank you for your help, I am sorry to have wasted so much of your time.